# Rspec Hash Matcher irrespective of keys order

Tags: rspec

## i have hash matching example written of this way

```
 it "expects the two hashes to be equal" do 
   h1 = {
     "name" => "pratam",
      "wisher" => "max mc"
   }

   h2 = {
     "wisher" => "max mc"
     "name" => "pratam"
   }

   expect(h1).to eq(h2)
 end
```

```
 rspec spec/m1.rb
```

output

```
 - {
     "name" => "pratam",
      "wisher" => "max mc"
   }

 + {
      "wisher" => "max mc",
      "name" => "pratam"
   }
```

But the above code doesnot seem to work what is the alternative to match irrespective of keys order in hashes

Answer (score 1):

The matcher is supposed to be irrespective of keys order:

Try this in your (clean) irb...

```
> require 'rspec'
 => true 
> include RSpec::Matchers
 => Object 
> h1 = {"name" => "pratam", "wisher" => "max mc"}
 => {"name"=>"pratam", "wisher"=>"max mc"}
> h2 = {"wisher" => "max mc", "name" => "pratam"}
 => {"wisher"=>"max mc", "name"=>"pratam"}
> expect(h1).to eq(h2)
 => true
```

There's no "dedicated" matcher for hashes, because this is how `eq` is supposed to work.

Maybe you have some "weird" gems that make some unexpected changes?

Comment: Indeed, `eq` uses `==` under the hood and that does not care about order: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-3D-3D

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/13fab582d6a2e857af66d1e4923fad6c94d627cc/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/eq.rb#L35